# RED5 - Configuration Issue - Records Partial Stream

Tags: video, installation, red5, configure, rtmp

I have installed Red5 in the most simplest manner. I'm working on an Ubuntu 12.10 32-Bit system. I just download and extracted the latest compiled version(1.0.0). I made the sh scripts executable and ran the server....Everything well and good...

And I finally notice that all the videos outputted to my streams folder are from almost half or one-third the length of the recording I did through Red5-Recorder.

I changed to another recorder; this time Flash-VideoIO, but the problem persists. I checked out the red5recorder's official demo and theirs seems to be working fine.

I even extracted the SWF, the config.xml and the JS files from their demo and tried them out with my red5 installation...No Use; same results.

Can someone help me out? Am I supposed to be configuring something??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this appears to be a known bug that users have identified on a number of different setups.

See: http://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/detail?id=312